# Way to get Chrome OS available upgrades via Google API

Tags: google-api, chromebook

is there any API to get the avail chrome os upgrades? i have searched a lot but only founf APIs for the resellers, i dont have a reseller account i just buy licences via a reseller

in the google admin it shows if you go to chrome os devices and click on the upgrades button on the menu bar

[image]
[image]

tried to search online but with no luck

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with this functionality but one way that you can attempt to determine underlying APIs is to use Chrome's Developer Tools' Network tab and see whether public endpoints are being accessed when you open|refresh that page. If there's a public API|method for this, you should see the call being made and the displayed data being returned. Another approach is to use the (mostly exhaustive) [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) and filter on e.g. "Chrome" or some other relevant descriptor.

Comment: I'm pleased to hear it. You're welcome!